# Square the min in a list?

Tags: prolog

So I know how to find the minimum in a list, but what if I wanted to square the result? Here is what I have to find the minimum:

```
min_in_list([Min],Min).           
min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :-
    H =< K,                            
    min_in_list([H|T],M).              
min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :-
    H > K,                              
    min_in_list([K|T],M).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile, but I think something like:

```
min_squared(List,Squared) :- min_in_list(List, Min), Squared is Min*Min.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to a function that multiplies its argument by itself?